# SSD for database or webpage files?

Tags: mysql, ssd, sata, windows-server-2012

I can have SSD for the mysql data files and system or the website files (.php files, images, video). I can not have both because of the SSD capacity I have.

What would be best, to make Windows 2012 and mysql on the SSD or the web files?

Does anybody knows, does every .php request reads php file from the disk or are they cached? If the are cached, it is probobaly better to have OS/mysql on SSD and other files on sata disk drives.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a really bad question - you've told us nothing about the volume of data of each type, the turnover of data, the level of demand, what you want to achieve, what the current disk provision actually is. BTW to answer these would take *at least* 2 screens of text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place the database on the SSD. When you update it, it has to write it back to the disk, which is costly. Source files hardly ever change, so they are cached directly in memory.

If you want the PHP files to be cached, install a PHP accelerator like eAccelerator which will cache the compiled code in memory. Placing text files on a SSD is a micro-optimisation that will get you no-where.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on many factors, but if you have a relatively big database, I'd say go with the database on SSD.

Comment: Thanx. The database is about 1 GB in space and there are about 60 tables, some with 500.000 records. If this is big or not I don't know, for my country it is not small, but I am from a small country ;-)